# can i catch the syscalls executed by linux program in an own c program?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

I want to ask if there is any possibility for catching the syscalls executed by another program on linux? 
so i can monitor what the program is doing on the system.

I already looked at the /proc/pid/ files but dont found anything related to this.

I want to program this on my own using the language c.

Comment: `man strace`....

Answer (score 4):

For non-programmatic use, you'd want [the `strace` command line utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace), but for programmatic use, you probably want to look at [the `ptrace` system call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace). Both of them can monitor processes that opt-in to monitoring (which can be done without that process's direct cooperation if they're launched by `strace` or by opt-ing in with `ptrace` after `fork`, before `exec`), or with sufficient privileges, existing processes.